# Vector, Matrix, Algebra class Design

Tags: c++, c++11

I am in the process of designing a maths library. I want to start with a simple vector 4 and a  matrix 4x4 and I'll extend it with the needs. I am trying to pro and cons of several design I have seen so that I can choose. I find it frustrating I searched a lot, I found a lot but almost no answer were talking about efficiency of the design which is critical for a maths library.

What I am taking into consideration, compiler are amazing now a days I know I can't be smarter that the compiler, but I want to help him to the max. C++11 is bringing good stuff, like move semantics and other stuff like std::tuple....

From what I know the data should be stored in continuous memory.

Where I am a bit lost and need more info is:

A) Should the data be:
value_type[ Rows * Cols] (simple c array) or
value_type* (allocated on the heap of size Rows * Cols) or use something like
std::tuple

B) Also Inheritance or composition/aggregation
I could have a template base class for the data or I could do it with composition/aggregation

C) I saw 3 layout of the data

- a struct and union (like in this article http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/4248/designing_fast_crossplatform_simd_.php)
- a simple member variable
- another one used static pointer to member instead of a union. (http://www.gamedev.net/topic/261920-a-slick-trick-in-c/)

D) Also in the gamasutra article (which seem to be old and compiler are better now) He say that the class should not have operator overload and that global function should be used instead. For example the crossProduct function to make it non-member instead of a member function.

I have all of those question, I know there is a lot. What are your take on those, especially on A and C.

Edit:

Thanks all for those answer for the point A, I must say that at the moment my biggest question is with point C, sorry I know it wasn't clear. Point c is really about the design of the classes. I saw 2 option (kind of three if you consider this static trick http://www.gamedev.net/topic/261920-a-slick-trick-in-c/) I could have for a Vector4 in example I could have members of x, y, z and w publicly available or I could also make a union with those members and an array, or I could have only an array and have functions X(), Y(), Z(), W() for accessor. And finally there is the static trick that I provided the link just above but I would prefer if  the x,y,z and w would be static and the array would be the data member.

Comment: "I am in the process of designing a math library." Yet another math library. Why?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: It could be for educational purposes

Comment: "just because" is also valid reason for doing any code.

Comment: You haven't said what the library would be used for. That's going to affect your design. Do you need 1000x1000 matrices for example? What hardware is it going to run on?

Comment: Also, don't avoid operator overloading. Operator overloads can be defined as global functions, so why avoid the readable approach? After compilation, there is no difference between applying an operator and calling a function.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde There is actually some overhead. I found that using functions that passed and returned by value provided the best speed for 4x4 matrices.

Comment: @ Cat Plus Plus: For multiple reasons: First to understand, I know I could use Eigen or uBLAS they would be overkill and I wouldn't learn as much, but I feel your pain. I want to understand the concequences of the design choice to make hopefully betterdesign choice.

Comment: @Steven: I doubt i'll need 1000x1000 for sure matrices 3x3 4x4 vector 3, 4 and maybe some a litle bit higher for tensor but that is still in like a year or so.

Comment: @Pubby8: But those operator should be inlined no? do you know where this overhead come from?

Answer (score 1):

For a small 4x4 matrix, I would avoid dynamically allocating memory on the heap ... a simple one-dimensional array that you can index as a 2D array should suffice (i.e., the ordered pair (x,y) value would be `matrix_array[COLUMNS * y + x]`), especially considering that loading any single value in the array will also cause adjacent values to be stored on the processor's cache-line, speeding up access to any adjacent elements.  The cache-loading can happen with heap-allocated memory as well, but the main reason to avoid heap allocation if possible for small matricies is that many sequential math operations will require you to return a temporary, and without r-value references, you're going to end up doing a lot of calls to `new` and `delete` inside the copy-constructors of those temporaries which will slow things down tremendously compared to quickly allocating memory on the stack.

Secondly, I would suggest you go with a templated approach, as this will let your define you matrix for not only plain-old-data-types like `double`, etc., but also for any secondary composite types you may decide to define later, or import from another library such as rationals, complex numbers, etc.  Whether you decide to add operator overloads is really up to you ... some people do not like it because it "hides" the complexity of what may be happening underneath the hood (i.e, `A * B` for `doubles` will be far simpler than `A * B` for a 4x4 `matrix<double>`).  On the other-hand, it can greatly simplify the amount of code you write for complex math operations.

Comment: I know operator overloading can be abused ... but in this case it allows programming close to the problem domain.  That's what the language feature was designed for, so IMHO this is an appropriate place to use it.  And as @Jason noted, it will make coding complex operations *much* easier (and less error-prone).

Comment: In your opinion considering the we have move semantics and that a default matrix would take almost 0 memory, you would still not implement it with a pointer and allocate?

Comment: @user994652: Your matrices are extremely small (at most 16 cells for now). For small pieces of data like this, there's not really a reason to pay the price associated with heap allocations. Just stick with the stack for now, worry about the heap when things expand a bit more. Plus, move semantics only help when "copying" the data of a temporary value into another memory location. Most of the temporaries in math come from large expressions which are in the process of being evaluated, so most would not even benefit from move semantics.

Comment: @Jason: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if he were to use a regular, static array, then there wouldn't be any performance hit if he declared it as a 2D array. Whether he has a 2D array indexed as `matrix_array[x][y]` or a 1D array indexed as `matrix_array[x*y+x]` shouldn't matter, because they compile down to the same thing (though, the 1D version would help for when he transitions to heap allocations)

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde - Yeah, there's no difference for a non-static data-member if it's a 2D-array or not ... as you noted, that would only really matter for heap allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/docs/blitz.html). Also see its "[About](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/whatis.html)" page to get a gist about it. It is one of the popular industrial strength math library written in C++. Though you didn't ask for which library to refer to I am citing this mainly because you can learn from some of the design choices made in this library. You might find insights on the very questions you are pondering.